Predicted probabilities from a multinomial mixed effect with two random intercept ignoring one of the two random effects
My data is about an experiment conducted on 243 partecipants over 100 verbs in Spanish.
Partecipants had to guess from which base word the verb comes from.
So, I have repeated measures for participants (ID) and verbs (ITEM). My response variable ACCURACY is a three-level non-ordered factor indicating whether the participant guessed correctly, did not guess, or preferred not to answer for a specific verb.
I fitted a multinomial mixed model using the mblogit() function from mclogit package:
mod.accuracy1 = mblogit(ACCURACY ~ fl.verbo*fl.base + fl.verbo*fl.fvfb +
        fl.base*fl.fvfb + TIPO + BASE, 
        random = list(ACCURACY ~ 1|ID, ACCURACY ~ 1|ITEM), 
        data = dati)

I would like to get predicted probabilities considering only the random intercept for ITEM.
My newdata object contains 100 rows, one for each ITEM, and the first element of ID. This is the structure:
> head(newdata)
  fl.verbo fl.base   fl.fvfb TIPO  BASE      ID      ITEM
1    5.820  12.655  0.001069    P  adj. MM83624    abajar
2    7.163   8.329  0.271126    P  adj. MM83624   embobar
3    0.000   6.753  0.000000    D  adj. MM83624   ariscar
4    8.314  12.633  0.013222    D  adj. MM83624 blanquear
5   11.358   0.000 11.357954    P noun. MM83624   ahorrar
6    1.099  10.633  0.000050    P  adj. MM83624   agrisar

With lmer one can use argument re.form = ~ (1|ITEM), but unfortunately the predict method for mblogit only allows to specific conditional = F in order to ignore all random effects.
I was successful in obtaining fitted values for linear predictor by ignoring random effects, and I was able to extract from the model the random intercept for ITEM
pred.conditional = predict(mod.accuracy1, newdata = newdata, type = "link", conditional = F)

random.item = mod.accuracy1$random.effects[[2]]

ind1 = grep("indovina", rownames(random.item))

ind2 = grep("non risponde", rownames(random.item))

random.indovina = random.item[ind1, ]

random.nonrisponde = random.item[ind2, ]

random.intercept = cbind(random.indovina, random.nonrisponde)

rownames(random.intercept) = levels(dati$ITEM)

colnames(random.intercept) = c("indovina", "non risponde")

> head(random.intercept)
           indovina non risponde
abajar      -1.6109     -0.03126
abarrancar   1.9898      1.67457
acalorar     2.6423     -0.29054
acedar      -3.6468      0.94759
acicatear   -2.5225      1.02941
acodillar    0.4278      0.19956

I think it's correct to compute the linear predictor via eta = pred.conditional + random.intercept:
> head(eta)
     indovina non risponde
[1,]   0.2845      -2.3046
[2,]   4.1670       0.1232
[3,]   1.5968      -0.3519
[4,]  -1.3894      -1.5974
[5,]  -8.9121      -2.3262
[6,]   1.2987      -0.5516

But from here I don't know how to get fitted probabilities for the three levels of the factor. How could I do it?
